# Copying values from one hash to another in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hashes, one big and one small. All of the smaller hash's keys show up in the bigger hash, but the values are different. I want to copy the values from the bigger hash to smaller hash.

E.G.:

```
# I have two hashes like so
%big_hash = (A => '1', B => '2', C => '3', D => '4', E => '5');
%small_hash = (A => '0', B => '0', C => '0');
# I want small_hash to get the values of big_hash like this
%small_hash = (A => '1', B => '2', C => '3');
```

An obvious answer would be to loop through the keys of the small hash, and copy over the values like this

```
foreach $key (keys %small_hash) { $small_hash{$key} = $big_hash{$key}; }
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: Fix your code: hash tables go with `()`, only hash table references go with `{}`.

Comment: Oops sorry about that, fixed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
@small_hash{ keys %small_hash } =  @big_hash{ keys %small_hash };
```

Comment: You are probably right to assume that that the order of `keys %hash` won't change between calls, but can it be guaranteed?

Comment: The OP wrote: "I want to copy the values from the bigger hash to smaller hash." Assuming he just wants to copy the values of keys also contained in `%small_hash`, this is the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, order of `keys` is guaranteed not to change.

Comment: Qtax: according to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html key order of keys are random, but guaranteed the **same** order until the hash does'nt change...

Comment: Moreover, the order of `values` is defined to match the order of `keys` provided the hash didn't change inbetween. You can rely on that one

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
%small = map { $_, $big{$_} } keys %small;
```

Altho that's pretty similar to the for loop.

```
$small{$_} = $big{$_} for keys %small;
```

---

[`map` **proof**](http://ideone.com/1PjLI) for those that need one:

```
my %big = (A => '1', B => '2', C => '3', D => '4', E => '5');
my %small = (A => '0', B => '0', C => '0');

%small = map { $_, $big{$_} } keys %small;

print join ', ', %small;
```

Output:

```
A, 1, C, 3, B, 2
```

Comment: No `map` operator needed to copy values from one table to another.

Comment: @Lumi, proof http://ideone.com/1PjLI Yeah, good manners to down vote correct answers.

Comment: @Lumi: Chris's answer is elegant. But here is no reason downvoting Qtax's answer, because it is ok too. upvoting.

Comment: @jm666, @Qtax - Downvote removed. :) As stated, I only downvoted *in return*. Btw, Qtax, I never said your answer was incorrect. Just `map` looks overblown when a hash table slice will do.